# CSS animation is not working

Tags: html, css

Why css animation is not working in my code. When i want to hover my link.

```
.floridabt-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #f9dd04;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.floridabt-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus:before, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover:before{
    content: "\2192";
    color: #222222;
    padding-right: 10px;
    -moz-transition: padding-right .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: padding-right  .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: padding-right  .3s ease-in;
    transition: padding-right  .3s ease-in; 
}
```

Comment: You need to set `transition: all 0.3s ease;` on the element without the `:hover` in the selector

Comment: It's also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the snippet. Now the transition works.

1. ul was missing in the selector
2. first css rule need of any declaration of `padding`
3. you have to put the `transition` declaration into the first rule (not under hover or focus)
4. in the second css rule you have to use `padding` and not `padding-right`
5. in the second css rule you don't need of `transition` declaration

I hope I was of any help.

```css
.floridabt-nav .dropdown-menu>ul>li>a, .dropdown-menu>ul>li>a{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #f9dd04;
 -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease-in;
 -o-transition: padding 0.3s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease-in;
 transition: padding 0.3s ease-in; 
 padding: inherit;
}
.floridabt-nav .dropdown-menu>ul>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>ul>li>a:hover{
 color: #222222;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floridabt-nav">
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#">PADDING TRANSITION</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```